# Validating dropdowns using Jquery

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have 3 dropdowns namely F1, F2 and F3. If F1 **OR** F2 value **<>** "Yes" then pop message, please choose F3 value to "No" before form can be submitted

```
<script>
    function formVal() {
        var F1= $("[title='Final One']").val(),
            F2= $("[title='Final Two']").val(),
            F3= $("[title='Final Three']").val();
        if(F1 === 'Yes' && F2 === 'Yes') {
            return true;
        }

        if(F3 == 'Yes') {
            return true;
        }

        alert('Error: please choose F3 value to "No" before form can be submitted');
        return false;
</script>
```

Comment: Tell us what about your code isn't working. Does it not run at all? Does it not display the error? Does it display the error every time?  If you `alert(F1);` do you get the value you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the PreSaveItem() to validate your form? If not, I'd use that before hand.

```
<script>
    function formVal() {
        var F1= $("[title='Final One']").val(),
            F2= $("[title='Final Two']").val(),
            F3= $("[title='Final Three']").val();
        if((F1 === 'No With Exception' || F2 === 'No With Exception') && F3 === 'Yes') {            
          alert ("Please select F3 to No before submission");              
        }
        else
        {
           return true;
        }

        return false;
</script>
```

Comment: If you are trying to reply, use the comments. Why call the function in the PreSaveAction? Just put all the logic in the formVal into the PreSaveAction function. Also, if you have your own Submit button, what is the onclientclick look like?

Comment: I am confuse, what is **===** ? Is it not equal to 'Yes' so user is choosing "No", correct?

Comment: The identity (===) operator behaves identically to the equality (==) operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal. (The == operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions. The === operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type === will simply return false).

Comment: @RohitWaghela, my dropdown values are with "Yes" and "No With Exception" so which is the right operator if I want to use equal or not equal to Yes and equal or not equal to "No with exception"? Thanks

Comment: @normsp check my edit.

Comment: @Mike, before the submission, if F1= "No With Exception" OR F2="No with Exception", If F3="yes" then pop-up error. The validation should tell user F3 cannot be yes if either F1 or F2 is "No with Exception"

Comment: Ok, see my second edit.